# Project Management on a team with diverse skill set?

Tags: agile, software-development, project-management-style, tracking, gantt

Assume I have 2-3 Objectives (OKRs), and 1 to 3 Key Results (KR) per Objective.

Today here’s my workflow:

- I work with my team during grooming sessions to get a high level cost to achieve the KR. I do this by breaking the KR into multiple stories and T-shirt sizing those stories.
- I prioritize the Objectives and KRs by assessing impact vs complexity. I prioritize 1) low-hanging fruits and 2) high impact and complex KRs (typically with the longest poll) that require de-risking and an early start.
- Once I understand priorities, I overlay the KRs with the complexity (i.e. man-months) and I build a Gantt Chart with each KR 1 (or more) work streams.
- I use the complexity numbers to identify when can a work stream start and what can go in parallel.

The problem is that the above assumes that each engineer on the team is fungible and can move anywhere up and down the stack. I worked in a team like that and the above strategy almost always worked.

I’m my current team, engineers aren’t fungible, you have the Front End, Back End, and Data Engineers. So it feels I need to build 3 Gantt Charts (one per Engineering focus area) and can only complete a work stream once the same work stream across all Gantt Charts complete.

Q1. This seems overly complex, how do managers do this effectively? Is there a better way? Should I continue following my original approach even though it’s not accurate?

Q2. Do you see downsides to my methodology? Any recommendations or improvements?